# install psycopg2 for conda fails (windows)

Tags: installation, ipython, psycopg2, conda, miniconda

I would like to use psycopg2 (2.5.2) with conda (miniconda 3.0.5) on a Windows 8 machine. I am able to install it with a windows installer and it works with python and idle but I can't get it to run with ipython notebook or ipython. The command "conda install psycopg2" returns Error: No packages found matching: psycopg2. Do you have any advice?

Thank you for your help,
Nick

Comment: Have you tried using `pip` from the Anaconda installation?

Comment: I can confirm that a `pip install` works on windows if you use the wheels format (which is default now if the packager provides it).

Answer (score 11):

Try searching for the package with binstar:

> C:\Anaconda>binstar search -t conda psycopg2

You may need to install the Binstar command line client with

> conda install binstar

The command line search doesn't show "Platforms", so you will likely want to use web search:

> https://binstar.org/search?q=psycopg2

Follow the link for the package name that matches your platform and the next page will show the conda install command for that Binstar package.  For example:

> conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/jonrowland psycopg2

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @MattDMo using pip worked for on Windows 8:

```
pip install Psycopg2
```

Comment: Side note: requires visual C++ to compile it

Comment: For others that may need it, I needed to run `activate <environment_name>` before running this `pip` command (replace `<environment_name>` with the name of the ana/miniconda environment you wish to use)